# What will be LINQ MVC query equivalent to given SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have written an SQL query which works fine. I need its equivalent query in LINQ MVC.

```
select sum(od.QUANTITY*od.PRODUCT_PRICE)
 from ORDERS as o 
 inner join ORDER_DETAILS as od
 on o.ID = od.ORDER_ID where o.IS_DELIVERED = 1
 AND o.IS_CANCELED = 0;
```

I tried to form it myself and ended up with the query mentioned below, but it's not working for me;

```
var sum = from order in dbContext.ORDERS
          join orderDetails in dbContext.ORDER_DETAILS
          on order.ID equals orderDetails.ORDER_ID
          where order.IS_DELIVERED == true && order.IS_RETURNED_BACK == false
          select new { sum = dbContext.ORDER_DETAILS.Sum(od => od.QUANTITY * od.PRODUCT_PRICE) };
```

Comment: Are you trying to sum all orders?

Answer (score 1):

If your DbContext has proper relational mappings, the below code works

```
dbContext.ORDERS.ORDER_DETAILS
     .Where(x => x.IS_CANCELLED == 0 && o.IS_RETURNED_BACK == false)
     .Sum(od => od.PRODUCT_PRICE)
```

If it doesn't you need to use join

```
var result = (from o in dbContext.ORDERS
join od in dbContext.ORDER_DETAILS
  on o.ID  equals od.ORDER_ID
where o.IsCancelled == 0 && && o.IS_RETURNED_BACK == false
select od.PRODUCT_PRICE).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant to do? This will create a list of order detail total and then sum the list to give you a value.

```
   var sum = (from order in dbContext.ORDERS
                  join orderDetails in dbContext.ORDER_DETAILS
                  on order.ID equals orderDetails.ORDER_ID
                  where order.IS_DELIVERED == true && order.IS_RETURNED_BACK == false
                  select new { orderDetailTotal = od.QUANTITY * od.PRODUCT_PRICE) }).Sum(x => x.orderDetailTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the `ORDERS` object should have a list of `ORDER_DETAILS` if done with proper relational mappings. Also the `IS_DELIVERED` and `IS_RETURNED_BACK` should be Booleans if mapped properly. In that case, you don't need an explicit join and your C# LINQ can be as simple as:

```
var sum = (from o in dbContext.ORDERS
           where o.IS_DELIVERED && !o.IS_RETURNED_BACK
           select new { Total = o.ORDER_DETAILS.QUANTITY * o.ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCT_PRICE }
          ).Sum(x => x.Total);
```

Also, ideally the objects should've been named in pascal-case and without the underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need select clause, you can use Sum function on query result and specify lambda expression for field calculation you need.

```
var sum = (from order in dbContext.ORDERS
                  join orderDetails in dbContext.ORDER_DETAILS
                  on order.ID equals orderDetails.ORDER_ID
                  where order.IS_DELIVERED == true && order.IS_RETURNED_BACK == false).Sum(x=> x.QUANTITY * x.PRODUCT_PRICE)
```